# Is it possible to make text in a matlab GUIDE app selectable (and possible to copy) but not editable?

Tags: matlab, matlab-guide

Like question in title says. I would like a text field that should be possible to select just like text you would in a browser, but not editable.

I tried setting the Enable property to off and inactive. I also tried using both text fields and edit texts and static text boxes. Edit text boxes with Enable set to on allows me to select it, but not copy it. I don't know if there could be OS specific issues (Ubuntu 16.04) since matlab seems to like to use other key shortcuts for copy paste in Linux. Funny enough, when I right-click the selectable text, nothing happens.

It should work in GUIDE, so I imagine there is just some setting in properties manager I missed.

Comment: For the right-click behaviour, you have to code it yourself (e.g. add a [`uicontextmenu`](https://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/uicontextmenu.html) to your text box). For your other question, if your final goal is to just copy the full text to the clipboard, there is a nice trick described [here](https://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/uicontrol.html#f52-578590) (in the "tip" section). Otherwise no, there is no simple way to react/prevent text modification on the fly, matlab will only fire an event (letting you interact) once the focus leaves the text box (or enter is pressed).

Comment: An inactive editbox is the way to go imho. You can change the shortcut keys to be windows-like in `Settings >> MATLAB >> Keyboard >> Shortcuts >> Active settings: Windows Default Set` (it's probably on "Emact Default Set" at the moment).

Answer (score 2):

There is a way to achieve that but (i) not directly in GUIDE, and (ii) not even in pure MATLAB. This solution relies on undocumented underlying java properties of the MATLAB `edit` box.

To be able to access these properties, you first need to download the [`finjobj`](https://mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/14317-findjobj-find-java-handles-of-matlab-graphic-objects) utility from the file exchange.

Armed with that, the following code works fine on MATLAB R2015a, you may have to adjust or fiddle for other MATLAB versions.

Code for `demo_editbox_interception.m`:

```
function h = demo_editbox_interception

% create minimalistic text box
h.fig = figure('Toolbar','none','Menubar','none') ;
h.ht = uicontrol('style','edit','Position',[20 20 300 30],...
    'String','This is a multi-word test string');

% find the handle of the underlying java object
h.jt = findjobj(h.ht) ;
% disable edition of the java text box
h.jt.Editable = 0 ;
% => This leaves you with a text box where you can select all or part of
% the text present, but you cannot modify the text.

%% Now add copy functionality:
% choose which functionality you want from the options below: 
% set(h.ht,'ButtonDownFcn',@copy_full_string)
set(h.ht,'ButtonDownFcn',{@copy_selection,h.jt} )


function str = copy_full_string(hobj,~)
    % this function will copy the ENTIRE content of the edit box into the
    % clipboard. It does NOT rely on the undocumented java properties
    str = get(hobj,'String') ;
    clipboard('copy',str)
    disp(['String: "' str '" copied into the clipboard.'] )


function str = copy_selection(hobj,evt,jt)
    % this function will copy the SELECTED content of the edit box into the
    % clipboard. It DOES rely on the undocumented java properties
    str = jt.SelectedText ;
    clipboard('copy',str)
    disp(['String: "' str '" copied into the clipboard.'] )
```

---

You can see it in effect. Select text with the left mouse button, and fire the callback (the copy) with the right button:

[image: demo gif]